# RESTful API: how to distinguish users requests from front-end requests?

Tags: rest, http, authentication, hapi.js

So, I have a RESTful API (built with Hapi.js) that has endpoints consumed by users and my front-end app (built with Next.js). `GET api/candies` is one of them, I'll take it as an example.

The front-end asks the list of candies stored in my DB and displays them on a page anyone can access (it has to be this way). The front-end doesn't provide an API token since people could read/use it. But, users who want to get this list of candies (to build whatever they want with it) must provide a valid API token (which they get by creating an account on my front-end app).

How could my API tell if a request for `api/candies` is from a user or from my front-end app, so it can verify (or not) the validity of their token?

I'm wondering if my problem isn't also about web scraping.

Can anyone help me please? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about the same problem a while ago. If your frontend has a client side REST client (JS+XHR/fetch), then I don't think it is possible to do this reliably, because no matter how you identify your frontend REST client, your users will be able to copy it just by checking the HTTP requests in browser via CTRL+SHIFT+I. There are even automation tools, which use the browser e.g. Selenium. If you have a server side REST client (e.g. PHP+CURL), then just create a consumer id for the frontend and use a token. Even in this case I can easily write a few lines of code that uses the frontend for the same request. So if you want to sell the same service for money that you provide for free on your frontend, then you are out of luck here. This does not mean that there won't be consumers who are willing to pay for it.

I think your problem is bad business model.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear explanation!
You're right, the business model was the problem.
I'll accept your answer as a solution as it explains why the problem can't be solved with some code :)

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can be addressed by inspecting different headers sent by different user agents. You can also add custom headers from your front-end and validate the same on the backend.